# Spring Cache Abstraction is not working with HystrixObservableCommand

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, spring-cache

I am using Spring Cloud of version Edgware.SR3. I have implemented the Caffine caching with the use of Spring Caching Abstraction. We are also using Hystrix. For Hystrix we are not using annotation based approach.

Below are the required code.

**UserRepositoryImpl.Java**

```
//..  code
@Override
    public Observable<Optional<List<User>>> getUserList(final String status) {
        return new HystrixObservableCommand<Optional<List<User>>>(
                HystrixObservableCommand.Setter.withGroupKey(
                        hystrixCommandGroupKey).andCommandKey(
                        HystrixCommandKey.Factory.asKey("getUserList"))) {
            @Override
            protected Observable<Optional<List<User>>> construct() {
                return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Optional<List<User>>> subscriber) -> {
                    try {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            System.out.println("##############Database Call getUserList");
                            //.. Database call or http call
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //.. Some exception Handling
                    } finally {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            protected Observable<Optional<List<User>>> resumeWithFallback() {
                return Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Optional<List<User>>> subscriber) -> {
                    try {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            System.out.println("##############Database Call getUserList");
                            //.. Database call or http call
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //.. Some exception Handling
                    } finally {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }.toObservable();
    }

//..  code
```

**UserService.java**

```
//.. code
  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "UserListCache", key = "#status")
   public Observable<Optional<List<User>>> listUsersAsync(final String status){
    return userRepository.getUserList(status);
   }
//.. code
```

Getting below exception.

```
com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: getUserList command executed multiple times - this is not permitted.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$7.call(AbstractCommand.java:461) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$7.call(AbstractCommand.java:454) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) [rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10247) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10214) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10054) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar:1.2.0]
    at com.j2.billing.mvc.controller.AdminController.listUsers(AdminController.java:68) ~[main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at com.j2.billing.mvc.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:110) ~[main/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This instance can only be executed once. Please instantiate a new instance.
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$7.call(AbstractCommand.java:459) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.12.jar:1.5.12]
    ... 80 common frames omitted
```

I have some other caching methods using Observable (without HystrixObservableCommand) are working without any issue.

Can some one please help me to figure out this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are caching `Observable` object that was created by `HystrixObservableCommand`. This observable execute HystrixCommand that it contains when it is subscribed.

As a result, if you caches `Observable` and reuse it later, it will result in using the same HystrixCommand multiple times and it is not allowed.

What you need to cache is `Optional<List<User>>`, not `Observable<Optional<List<User>>>`.